# Deserialize a JSON in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

When I try to Deserialize a JSON by the instruction:

```
Root outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(temp);
```

It does not work!

I have validated the JSON and is valid (with http://jsonlint.com/)

The contents of "temp" is as follows (I checked at runtime)

```
{"root": 
       {"ajaxResponse": {
                       "credits": {"availableCredits": 998,
                       "total": "1000",
                       "used":"2"
                        },
                       "success": 1
                        }
        }
}
```

My class structure is as follows:

```
public class Root
 {
      public AjaxResponse ajaxResponse {get; September;}
 }


public class Credits
{
     public int availableCredits {get; September;}
     public string Total {get; September;}
     public string used {get; September;}
}

public class AjaxResponse
{
     public credits Credits {get; September;}
     public int success {get; September;}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is `{get; September;}`? Try posting code that isn't garbage.

Comment: Also, `credits Credits` should be `Credits credits`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let [Json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) do work for you. It generates C# class structure for given json content.

Generated class structure is like this:

```
public class Credits
{
    public int availableCredits { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string used { get; set; }
}

public class AjaxResponse
{
    public Credits credits { get; set; }
    public int success { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public AjaxResponse ajaxResponse { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Root root { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize logic should be:

```
RootObject outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(temp);
```

Comment: Great. May i know the reason then why you un-accept the answer if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
public class Container
{
    public Root root {get;set;}
}
```

And use like this:

```
var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(temp);
```

Complete sample:

```
void Main()
{
var temp = @"
{""root"": 
    {""ajaxResponse"": {
                    ""credits"": {""availableCredits"": 998,
                    ""total"": ""1000"",
                    ""used"":""2""
                        },
                    ""success"": 1
                        }
        }
}
";
    var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(temp);
    outObject.Dump();
}

public class Container
{
    public Root root {get;set;}
}

public class Root
{
    public AjaxResponse ajaxResponse {get; set;}
}


public class Credits
{
    public int availableCredits {get; set;}
    public string total {get; set;}
    public string used {get; set;}
}

public class AjaxResponse
{
    public Credits credits {get; set;}
    public int success {get; set;}
}
```